# How do I move audio from one portion to another in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I want to select a portion of audio and then move it by dragging it to different areas in the same track.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Ctrl + I to split track, F5 to move selected by F1 part of the track

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can move tracks around without cutting and pasting!

At the top of the Audacity screen, just right of the transport buttons there are several "Tool" buttons. Click this button:

[image: Timeshift tool]

This is called the Timeshift tool. Use the Timeshift tool to move tracks along the timeline. After selecting the Timeshift tool, select a track by clicking on the waveform and dragging it left or right to move it earlier or later in the timeline. Or you can click on the waveform and move it to any other track anywhere on the timeline.

Credit to wikieducator.org/Using_Audacity/Moving_tracks

Comment: Timeshift tool seems to be the correct answer, only when I click on the track, the cursor just moves around ... see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FvUIHeI0OQ

Comment: And now it seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the portion of audio you want to move with the mouse
2. Cut the selection (either with the keyboard - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on Windows/Linux and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on Mac - **or** with the mouse - click on the Cut icon in the toolbar or go to Edit → Cut)
3. Select the place you want to move it to with the mouse.
4. Paste the selection (either with the keyboard - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows/Linux and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac - **or** with the mouse - click on the Cut icon in the toolbar or go to Edit → Paste)

There is no way to move audio clips around via drag-'n'-drop.

Comment: I want to use just mouse to select,and then drag to move the portion.Isnt it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is wondering about this while using recent versions, time shift functionality mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1079096/1145698) was removed and replaced with this barely visible draggable part near the top:

[image: Draggable part]